# Jest test Fat Arrow in class missing this

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this, jestjs, ecmascript-2017

I'm writing unit tests for a Component in Jest and I'm currently just testing functionality.

The class function is as followed:

```
class Comp extends Component {

    fetch = null;

    update = async () => {
        try {
            if(this.fetch)
                this.fetch.cancel();

            // Do stuff
            this.fetch = createFetch();

            await this.fetch();
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Error in update!!!', e);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
             <div></div>
        )
    }
}
```

The jest test looks like this:

```
test('Should call fetch.cancel if fetch exists', async () => {
    const spy = jest.fn();
    const comp = new Comp();

    comp.fetch = {cancel: spy};

    await comp.update();

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

But I'm getting this error from the update function:

> Error in update!!! ReferenceError: _this3 is not defined

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Could you try without arrow functions ?

Comment: The rest of the functionality would crash.
It's also so I don't have to use fn.bind(this) in the other parts of the component

Comment: i assume the problem is not the arrow function in jest, but the class property in your Comp class. take a look at this: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/

Comment: When do you get this error, when you run your test or when you execute this on your browser?

Comment: @VivekN It's a Jest test execution, so command line.

Comment: @luschn It worked! Well, almost. For some reason I needed to add {"spec": true} as well. If you can put that in as the answer, I'll accept it :)

Comment: thanx, added some info about the spec mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the problem is not the arrow function in Jest, but the class property in your Comp class. Take a look at this: http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties

Edit: It worked after setting the spec mode: http://2ality.com/2017/01/babel-esm-spec-mode.html

> Modules transpiled in this mode conform as closely to the spec as is
>   possible without using ES6 proxies